# Storing password to database in private repository ok with GDPR?

Tags: database, security

We have a database that is storing sensitive user-data. The connectionstring is in web.config and the web.config is on bitbucket in our private repository.
Now this GDPR law.. does it say anything about that? Are we at fault and should we for THAT reason remove the web.config from the repository (or remove the connectionstring from the web.config) ?